# How to check if string exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I wanted to loop through an array and check if a string exists in the array elements and my code below partially works. The problem is currently it logs the array element if a specified string exists anywhere in the array element but what I want to do is log if the string is in the array element but also the same index position. To explain this better say one of my array elements is `testing` and the string I'm looking for is `tes` because `tes` is occurring in the index position 0,1,2 the element logs. But say my array element is `not testing` and the string I'm looking for is `tes` it won't log because even though the string exists it's in the wrong index. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```js
const myArray = ['test blah', 'this is test', 'testing 234', 'nothing']

const check = 'te'
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].includes(check)) {
    //should print myArray[0] and myarray[2]
    console.log(myArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startsWith()`

```js
const myArray = ['test blah', 'this is test', 'testing 234', 'nothing']

const check = 'tes'
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].startsWith(check)) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
  }
}
```